# how to pass file to docker image?

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have an application which I have dockerize it. The application recieves a configuration file which can change per user. I used the following command to pass config file to the image.

```
docker run --rm --name $(PROJECT_NAME) -v $(pwd)/config.yaml:/root/config.yaml
```

I don't want to build the image again for a new config file. but it doesn't seems to work as when I inspected the contents of the file on the container it showed me the same file. It seems that when I change the file on my local system and pass it to the container in run command, the change is not reflected and it loads previous config file. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or any best practices to deal with such a scenario.

Dockerfile

```
    # base image
    FROM amazonlinux:2

    # copy requirements file to working directory
    COPY requirements.txt ./

    RUN yum -y install python3 \
        && pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

    COPY app/. ./

    ENTRYPOINT python3 run.py config.yaml
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change the last line to: ENTRYPOINT python3 run.py /root/config.yaml

Comment: it gives me the following error : IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/root/config.yaml'

Comment: That indicates that `/root/config.yaml` is a directory rather than a file.

What is the the output of `docker run --rm --name $(PROJECT_NAME) -v $(pwd)/config.yaml:/root ls -lrt /root` ?

Comment: Also, what is your current directory ($PWD) Do you have the config file in there? Are you running this from Linux or windows?

Comment: I was able to resolve it. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it. Here is my updated Docker file : I have put my config file in **config/** folder and mount it. Now I can build the image once and can change the config file inside the **config/** folder and changes will be reflected inside the container.

```
# base image
FROM amazonlinux:2

# copy requirements file to working directory
COPY requirements.txt ./

COPY app/. ./

RUN yum -y install python3 \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT python3 run.py config/config.yaml
```

This is the run command:

```
docker run --rm --name $(PROJECT_NAME) -v $(CONFIG_PATH):/config $(DOCKER_REPO)

CONFIG_PATH = $(PWD)/config
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see is "normal".

When you mount a file or directory, you actually mount a pointer (inode) inside the container. It's the way docker work with volume.

Some/most editor use a "safe write" method that consist to write a new file and replace the old file with the new one. When the editor do that, the new updated file have a new pointer (inode) and the old one still exist pointing to the old content.

On linux, a file is only deleted when no one use it, it's why you can't see it but the container still have it.

You will have the same problem if you mount a directory and you delete it and recreate one with the same name, the container will not see the new directory.

It's a know limitation of the bind mount and the best you can do is to mount a directory with your file inside. The other way is to restart your container, Docker will find the new inode and use it.